# What is the name of a group of containers created with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker-compose

When using Docker Compose, the created containers usually share the same network and may share volumes. Therefore I would say, this group of containers is somewhat similar to a [pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) in Kubernetes:

> Pods are the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.
>
> A Pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more containers, with shared storage and network resources, and a specification for how to run the containers. A Pod's contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context. A Pod models an application-specific "logical host": it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled. In non-cloud contexts, applications executed on the same physical or virtual machine are analogous to cloud applications executed on the same logical host.

On the other hand, the word "pod" never appears in the [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/). The only word that is actually used for the started containers is "(application) stack", as in:

> The big advantage of using Compose is you can define your application stack in a file, ...

Although I would say, this is a terribly uninformative name, considering the shared resources and usually linked lifetimes.

So is there a commonly used name for the group of containers?

Comment: *Stack* is the word, what is wrong about it ?

Comment: "Stack" sounds like a bunch of containers, that are just coincidentally created at the same time, like variables on the memory stack. This does not sound like Compose has to be used to create one.

Comment: A stack is a set of services. Compose is just a tool to manage stacks easily (start/stop services, create networks, volumes, etc). Of course you can manage services without it.

Comment: I think I am fine with "stack". Just wanted to make sure.